# How to avoid this artifacts in baking?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

i have some problems with artifacts in baked textures. It is basically a very simple scene but cycles render beautiful artifacts in my images, at least in baking mode (see pictures). The source of the problem seems clear: if i bevel the edge, i will have these artifacts, but i dont know how to fix this. In my opinion this is a bug in blender but maybe somebody has an workaround.

What i have done is simple:

1. Create a cube
2. Delete some faces
3. Apply scale
4. Flip normals (because they were the inner faces of the cube)
5. Unwrap
6. Bake

[image: Artifacts]

[image: Bevel]

Comment: If you think that's a bug, just report it *(In Blender > Help > Report a Bug)*.

Comment: I will wait some days if somebody knows what is going on here, but i dont see any reason why there should be this kind of horizontal-edge-color-gradients across the texture. Edges should never be visible this way, not even in freestyle mode.